# How can I tell which application I'm running in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-zeppelin

I use Zeppelin to run Spark queries and we have the Spark application UI.

[image]

But, we only have one of the UI views for each of the running applications.

https://spark-history-server.[myURL].com/history/application_112378123821_98123

I have Zeppelin running on Hadoop. I'd like to find out what my application ID should be.

Is there a way that I can find this out from within a Zeppelin notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`sc.applicationId`** to get the application id for the current job.

**`Using Spark Session:`**

```
spark.sparkContext.applicationId
```

Comment: This is literally awesome. Do you have any recommendations for how can I learn about interpreting the Zeppelin application UI?

Comment: @Cauder, Here is the official documentation from `Zeppelin UI` https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/quickstart/explorezeppelinui.html for `Spark application UI` https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/web-ui.html https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html